# R: Finding and inverting intervals in dataframe and then report when changed

Tags: r

I have a dataframe containing positions as integers. 
Example:

```
start    stop    strand
1        10      +
3        8       +  
11       9       +
```

I would like to switch values of start and stop en the third row, aswell to have the strand change from "+" to "-".

Edit: This is function works.

```
strandFun <- function(x){
    if(x[2] > x[1]) 
    {
        return("+")
    } else {
        return("-")
    }
}

apply(df, 1, strandFun)
```

And then use `cbind()` to put it into my dataframe.

To switch around the values when start is greater then stop I would use:

```
start[start>stop] <- stop
stop <- abs(stop)
```

but here I get the following error:

"number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"

Is there a fancy way to solve my problems?

Comment: of course it always assigns "+" because you have `if (TRUE) "+"`.. why are you doing that?

Comment: wouldn't it be FALSE if x[1]>x[2]?

Comment: `TRUE` will never be `FALSE`, you need to put something inside the `if()` parentheses that could have a chance of evaluating to either if you ever want to receive `"-"` correctly.

Comment: I think you meant to put `val` in there

Comment: Oh yeah - of course. I didn't think straight. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)
dt[start > stop, names(dt) := list(stop, start, "-")]
#    start stop strand
# 1:     1   10      +
# 2:     3    8      +
# 3:     9   11      -
```

`dt` is shown below.

If instead, you'd like to *invert* the strand, then:

```
dt[start > stop, names(dt) := list(stop, start, ifelse(strand == "+", "-", "+")]
```

---

```
dt = fread('start    stop    strand
1        10      +
3        8       +  
11       9       +')
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use some basic assignment calls after indexing to see if `stop` is less than or equal to `start`

```
sel <- with(df, stop <= start)
df[sel,c("start","stop")] <- df[sel,c("stop","start")]
df[sel,c("strand")] <- "-"

#  start stop strand
#1     1   10      +
#2     3    8      +
#3     9   11      -
```

The `df` used here was:

```
df <- read.table(text="start    stop    strand
1        10      +
3        8       +  
11       9       +",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: I get the error:
Error in df[sel, c("stop", "start")] : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: @MadsObi - nope, code works fine on a clean session here. Did you create `df` first?

Answer (score 1):

Yup, here's a moderately fancy way.

```
library(dplyr)

df.ID = df %>% mutate(ID = 1:n())

df.unchanged = df.ID %>% filter(start <= stop)

result = 
  df.ID %>%
    filter(start > stop) %>%
    mutate(strand = "-",
           old_start = start,
           start = end,
           end = old_start) %>%
    select(-old_start) %>%
    bind_rows(df.unchanged) %>%
    arrange(ID)
```

Comment: Can I get you to elaborate on what happens in the first line?

Comment: `library(dplyr)` loaded the dplyr package

Comment: Sorry, I meant the second line :) More specifically the arguments used in mutate()

Comment: It adds an ID column. That way, after the data is split into two and put back together again, there's a way to put it back in order.